# Function only works on one div?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck... I can't seem to get a function to fire off on the divs below the first one.... any suggestions?

Comment: Please, specify this a bit more. Preferably, also paste here piece of code you work with.

Comment: Please be more specific and include the relevant code.

Comment: Moses supposes we can diagnosis without the codeses.... :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are using something like this:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv")
```

With HTML like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">Hello World</div>
<div id="myDiv">Hello Again</div>
```

In which case, you can't use the same ID for two div tags and the divs after your first one won't be affected by your JavaScript.

You can use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

To get a collection of all your divs, you could then test them to see if you want to do something with them, for example by giving them all the same class.

Comment: By rights having two ids that are the same makes the html invalid so each id should be unique so the problem above should not occur.